# What's wrong with my code, I am signing a transaction? Invalid v,r,s error?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, ecdsa

```c
func main() {
    privateKey, err := crypto.GenerateKey()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    auth := bind.NewKeyedTransactor(privateKey)

    balance := new(big.Int)
    balance.SetString("10000000000000000000", 10) // 10 eth in wei

    address := auth.From
    genesisAlloc := map[common.Address]core.GenesisAccount{
        address: {
            Balance: balance,
        },
    }

    blockGasLimit := uint64(4712388)
    client := backends.NewSimulatedBackend(genesisAlloc, blockGasLimit)

    fromAddress := auth.From
    nonce, err := client.PendingNonceAt(context.Background(), fromAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    value := big.NewInt(1000000000000000000) // in wei (1 eth)
    gasLimit := uint64(21000)                // in units
    gasPrice, err := client.SuggestGasPrice(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    toAddress := common.HexToAddress("0x4592d8f8d7b001e72cb26a73e4fa1806a51ac79d")
    var data []byte
    tx := types.NewTransaction(nonce, toAddress, value, gasLimit, gasPrice, data)
    chainID := big.NewInt(1)
    signedTx, err := types.SignTx(tx, types.NewEIP155Signer(chainID), privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = client.SendTransaction(context.Background(), signedTx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("tx sent: %s\n", signedTx.Hash().Hex()) // tx sent: 0xec3ceb05642c61d33fa6c951b54080d1953ac8227be81e7b5e4e2cfed69eeb51

    client.Commit()

    receipt, err := client.TransactionReceipt(context.Background(), signedTx.Hash())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if receipt == nil {
        log.Fatal("receipt is nil. Forgot to commit?")
    }

    fmt.Printf("status: %v\n", receipt.Status) // status: 1
}
```

I am using the above code to send an ethereum Transaction but am not able to send it. It is showing :
panic: invalid transaction: invalid transaction v, r, s val

Any and all help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `chainID` to `1337` (Geth private chains (default))

```
chainID := big.NewInt(1337)
```

Test with your code:

```
$ go version
go version go1.10.4 linux/amd64
$ go run transaction.go 
tx sent: 0x2f80a25ddb20c614c9bfb47f964540f235c3f74a99b66d810df04816d40a453a
status: 1
```

It's a problem with the [simulated.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/accounts/abi/bind/backends/simulated.go). You can find more about the error [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/19699).

If still fails, update your packages cloning the [repo](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum).